# Javascript slideshow that gradually zooms on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I want something like this:

```
`http://codepen.io/docode/pen/EjyVQY`.
```

In this case, all I care about is the zooming aspect of this slideshow. How can I achieve this same zooming effect in JS instead of CSS? Keep in mind, I want the zooming to occur by itself. Not by a click or other event handler.

Thanks for your help! :)

**UPDATE:** Zooming effect  must be achieved while the width and height remain the same...

Comment: I'm not a real programmer. I'm just using a pre-built site and want this feature on it. Do you know how to help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="http://docode.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/pictures/pic-3.jpg"/>
<img src="http://docode.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/pictures/pic-2.jpg"/>    
<img src="http://docode.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/pictures/pic-1.jpg"/>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;


}

#slideshow img {
   width:100%;
    height:100%;
   display:block;
    left:0;
    top:0;
   position:absolute;
    opacity:0;

}
```

JQuery:

```
images = $('#slideshow img');

i = 0;
anima(i);
setInterval(function() {

  if (i < images.length - 1) {

    i++;

  } else {
    i = 0;

  }
  anima(i);
}, 15000);

function anima(i) {

  $(images).eq(i).fadeTo(100, 0.8);
  $(images).eq(i).animate({
    width: '150%',
    height: '150%',
    top: '-25%',
    left: '-25%',
    opacity: 1
  }, 15000, "linear", function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {
      $(this).css('width', '100%');
      $(this).css('height', '100%');
      $(this).css('top', '0');
      $(this).css('left', '0');
    });

  });
}
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sinisake/w0jz31uc/show/ Play with values - speed it up, or slow it down, change width/height animation, if needed. This one can go full screen, but can be placed into some container on page, too.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a way to make the image have the same width and height when zooming? The other code zooms while staying still. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Np, yes... little different html structure is needed...

Comment: I'm awful at programming. Would you mind explaining the changes that are necessary?

Comment: Huh, actually, not so easy (without using of CSS3 you want to avoid)... But, also, if i understand CSS from your example - some re-scaling is applied there, too (transform:scale(1.1);) to background image... will see if i can make something closer to CSS demo you posted...

Comment: E.g. something like this - minimal re-scaling, + minimal movement... http://fiddle.jshell.net/w0jz31uc/5/

Comment: With overflow: hidden, works great! Thanks...